# Python - Make pymysql return a dictionary key with the value being a list of the results

Tags: python, mysql, dictionary, pymysql

When using pymysql.cursors.DictCursor, pymysql will return the results as separate dictionaries in  a list. For example, if the users table looks like this

```
userName  firstName
sharko     dan
weirdal    dan
```

then on `SELECT userName FROM users WHERE firstName = 'dan';` DictCursor would return

```
[{'userName': 'sharko'}, {'userName': 'weirdal'}]
```

Is there a way to make it return this?
`{userName:['sharko','weirdal']}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert the results into the desired form using a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) of lists:

```python
from collections import defaultdict

results = defaultdict(list)

query = 'SELECT userName FROM users WHERE firstName = %s'
for item in cursor.execute(query, ('dan',)):
    for k in item:
        results[k].append(item[k])
```

For your example this would result in:

```python
>>> results
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'userName': ['sharko', 'weirdal']})
```

If you want to, you can convert back to standard dict:

```python
>>> results = dict(results)
>>> results
{'userName': ['sharko', 'weirdal']}
```

Answer (score 0):

No.  You get one dict per row.  It's trivially easy to convert from what you have to what you want, of course.